# OrientDB share common database with two other

Tags: database, connection, orientdb

I have a common database project to store all of my users data (users from all my projects). (User's database)

and for each of projects, I want to use this common database and link to these data documents. (Project1's database, Project2's database)

how can I manage and link document(+edge +vertex) between two or more database, or If it is not yet possible, How can I solve my need?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, cross-database links are not supported by OrientDB (if it is what you mean).

If you want to use the graph API, the only solution you have is to use a single DB and store all the data there. You can use OrientDB security to profile the access to subsets of data for different users, if this is a requirement

Comment: tnx, maybe I separate data in a single database with multiple clusters.